# Why do tears fall from our eyes when we ride a bike too fast?

Tags: human-biology, human-eye

When we ride a bike too fast why do tears fall from our eyes. What is going on biologically and what may the evolutionary story be behind this?

This [quora Q&A](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-tears-fall-from-the-eyes-if-we-ride-a-bike-too-fast-Whats-the-hidden-reason-behind-this) gives a few ideas, none of which satisfy my question fully.

1. This is similar to a response to smoke.

   - But this is clean air? Why doesn't this happen all the time?
2. Our eyes always need to be lubricated.

   - But why the need for excess tears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our eyes need to be covered with a thin film of liquid all the time. When riding fast, the wind flow pushes the liquid away from your cornea. Your eye compensates for that by producing more tear.